# Which method is called when back to previous view via navigation controller?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I used navigation controller in my app. Back button is working fine, when it is tapped previous view is appearing. I need to know, in previous view, which method is getting called while appearing.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you go back the following methods will be called:

> Notifies the view controller that its view is about to be added to a
>   view hierarchy.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
}
```

> Notifies the view controller that its view was added to a view
>   hierarchy.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
}
```

Comment: Note that these methods are also called when the view controller is initially shown as well as when it becomes visible again when returning back to the view controller. Use `isMovingToParentViewController` to differentiate between the two.

Comment: @rmaddy indeed these functions are called every time. Regarding `isMovingToParentViewController`, this value is always `false` I have noticed. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

When your previous view is appearing, `viewWillAppear(:)` and `viewDidAppear(:)` called every time while view is appearing.

Answer (score 0):

When a view controller reappears

> - It will call **viewWillAppear(_:)** .. also you can define other view appearing methods like **viewDidAppear(_:)**
> - it will not call viewDidLoad()

Please check the Apple Document in detail to understand the View Controller Lifecycle

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/WorkWithViewControllers.html